# Python pandas dataframe and list merging

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a `pandas` DataFrame `df`:

```
         paper     reference
2171686  p84       r51
3816503  p41       r95
4994553  p112      r3
2948201  p112      r61
2957375  p32       r41
2938471  p65       r41
...
```

Here, each row of `df` shows the relationship of citation between `paper` and `reference` (where `paper` cites `reference`).

I need the following numbers for my analysis:

1. Frequency of elements of `paper` in `df`
2. When two elements from `paper` are randomly selected, the number of `reference` they cite in common

For number 1, I performed the following:

```
df_count = df.groupby(['paper'])['paper'].count()
```

For number 2, I performed the operation that returns pairs of elements in `paper` that cite the same element in `reference`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

pair = []
d = defaultdict(list)
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row['paper']].append(row['paper'])
for ref, lst in d.items():
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):
            pair.append([lst[i], lst[j], ref])
```

`pair` is a list that consists of three elements: first two elements are the pair of `paper`, and the third element is from `reference` that both `paper` elements cite. Below is what `pair` looks like:

```
[['p88','p7','r11'],
['p94','p33','r11'],
['p75','p33','r43'],
['p5','p12','r79'],
...]
```

I would like to retrieve a DataFrame in the following format:

```
paper1      freq1       paper2       freq2        common
p17         4           p45          3            2
p5          2           p8           5            2
...
```

where `paper1` and `paper2` represent the first two elements of each list of `pair`, `freq1` and `freq2` represent the frequency count of each paper done by `df_count`, and `common` is a number of `reference` both `paper1` and `paper2` cite in common.

How can I retrieve my desired dataset (in the desired format) from `df`, `df_count`, and `pair`?

Comment: Seems like you need a `crosstab` or pivot, i can't see how your expected output comes from your input tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be solved only using [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). I am not sure whether this is the most efficient way, though.

First, generate common reference counts:

```
# Merge the dataframe with itself to generate pairs
# Note that we merge only on reference, i.e. we generate each and every pair
df_pairs = df.merge(df, on=["reference"])

# Dataframe contains duplicate pairs of form (p1, p2) and (p2, p1), remove duplicates
df_pairs = df_pairs[df_pairs["paper_x"] < df_pairs["paper_y"]]

# Now group by pairs, and count the rows
# This will give you the number of common references per each paper pair
# reset_index is necessary to get each row separately
df_pairs = df_pairs.groupby(["paper_x", "paper_y"]).count().reset_index()
df_pairs.columns = ["paper1", "paper2", "common"]
```

Second, generate number of references per paper (you already got this):

```
df_refs = df.groupby(["paper"]).count().reset_index()
df_refs.columns = ["paper", "freq"]
```

Third, merge the two DataFrames:

```
# Note that we merge twice to get the count for both papers in each pair
df_all = df_pairs.merge(df_refs, how="left", left_on="paper1", right_on="paper")
df_all = df_all.merge(df_refs, how="left", left_on="paper2", right_on="paper")

# Get necessary columns and rename them
df_all = df_all[["paper1", "freq_x", "paper2", "freq_y", "common"]]
df_all.columns = ["paper1", "freq1", "paper2", "freq2", "common"]
```